# Overlay animated watermark multiple times

Tags: ffmpeg

So, I have this animated watermark (MOV w/alpha) that I want to overlay on top of a video. I want to do it multiple times, so once in the beginning, once in the middle and finally towards the end. I'd like to use ffmpeg. Issue is, I believe, that in the complex filtergraph I'd have to use, there will be multiple intermediates formed, leading to quality loss. Is there a way to do this in one-pass?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show some info about your `ffmpeg` build and your inputs. There complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i video -i overlay`

Comment: What means once in beginning, once in middle and finally towards the end? You want to overlay one timeline or something else?

Comment: Two movies - base movie and a short overlay movie with alpha. If the base is 45 minutes long, then the overlay happens at 0, 22.5 minutes and 45 minutes. I was hoping for a generic command where I didn't know the exact duration of base, but I don't think ffmpeg can reference input duration.